# Table Columns as parameters to Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamic SQL Error Converting nvarchar to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034441/dynamic-sql-error-converting-nvarchar-to-int)

Hi All,

I have created a stored procedure which takes the columns of a table as parameters and inserts into another table and the procedure looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE cagroup    (
  @DataID INT ,
  @days INT ,
  @GName VARCHAR(50) ,
  @T_ID INT ,
  @Act BIT ,
  @Key VARBINARY(16)
)
AS 
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @SchemaName SYSNAME
    DECLARE @TableName SYSNAME
    DECLARE @DatabaseName SYSNAME
    DECLARE @BR CHAR(2)
    SET @BR = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)

    SELECT  @SchemaName = Source_Schema ,
            @TableName = Source_Table ,
            @DatabaseName = Source_Database
    FROM    Source
    WHERE   ID = @DataID 



SET @SQL = 'INSERT  INTO ' + @DatabaseName + '.' + @SchemaName + '.'
            + @TableName + ' (' + @BR + 'GrName,' + @BR
            + '[To_ID],' + @BR + '[DataSoID],' + @BR
            + '[Active],' + @BR + 'S_R_ID'
            + @BR + ')' + @BR


SET @SQL = @SQL + 'SELECT ' + @GName + ' AS GrName ,' + @BR
                  + cast(@T_ID as NVARCHAR(10)) + ' AS To_ID ,' + @BR 
                  + cast(@DataID as NVARCHAR(10)) + ' AS DataSoID ,' + @BR
                  + cast(@Act as NVARCHAR(10)) + ' AS Active ,' + @BR 
                  + Key + ' AS key' + @BR 
                  + 'R_ID AS S_R_ID' + @BR 
                  + 'FROM' + @DatabaseName + '.'
                  + @SchemaName + '.' 
                  + @TableName + ' t' + @BR
                  + 'LEFT OUTER JOIN Gro g ON g.GName = '
                                 + @GName + @BR + 'AND g.Data_ID] =' 
                                 +cast(@DataID as NVARCHAR(10)) + @BR 
                                 + ' WHERE t.[I_DATE] > GETDATE() -' 
                                 + cast(@days as NVARCHAR(10)) + @BR
                                 + ' AND g.GName IS NULL
                                 AND ' + @GName + ' IS NOT NULL
                                 AND t.[Act] = 1' + @BR

    EXEC (@SQL)

END
```

Now I have to create some more of procedures like these but the problem is I am passing columns of a table as parameters so the other tables have 50 columns in a table and I don't want to have 50 parameters. So is there a better way to do it?