# While LOOP IN Dynamic QUERY

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamicquery

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @sqlQuery VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sqlQuery ='Select Style_Color, Style_Color_Desc as Description, 
 RPT, Weeks,  '

DECLARE @cnt INT = 1
DECLARE @TblCount NVARCHAR(1000) = (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM table_Name)            

WHILE @cnt <= @TblCount
BEGIN
    SET @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery + 'max(CASE WHEN Cluster_ID = (Select STORE_ID from Table_Name where id= '+@cnt+')
     then CAST(c.APS_Dev as decimal(10,2)) end) as ''APS Dev'' '


     SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
END

SET @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery+'                                          
 Minimum as Pres_Min  From table_Name '

PRINT(@SQLQuery)
END
```

I am getting error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Select Style_Color, Style_Color_Desc as Description,RPT, Weeks, Select STORE_ID from table_name where id= to data type int.

Some times when I do few changes getting this error

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

Could anyone help me how to declare while loop in dynamic query?

Comment: You're trying to add `@cnt` (an `INT`) to a string. If you want that number included in the string then you need to first `CAST` it

Comment: This is a mess. What are you really trying to do here? As posted you will have a bunch of columns with the same name. This is a classic xy problem. http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: I tried cast also but still I am getting error

Comment: I very strongly doubt that you need a while loop here to build dynamic sql. This has the look of something that would be really easy to do as a set based query. Please see this article if you really want some help. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic SQL error converting nvarchar to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034441/dynamic-sql-error-converting-nvarchar-to-int)

Comment: Yes, step way, WAY back from what you've done so far, and tell us what you're trying to do.  You have almost certainly started out in completely the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can use two variants:

1) to use `CAST` or `CONVERT` function

```
-- CAST
SET @sqlQuery += 'max(CASE WHEN Cluster_ID = (Select STORE_ID from Table_Name where id= '+CAST(@cnt AS varchar(5))+')
then CAST(c.APS_Dev as decimal(10,2)) end) as ''APS Dev'' '

-- CONVERT
SET @sqlQuery += 'max(CASE WHEN Cluster_ID = (Select STORE_ID from Table_Name where id= '+CONVERT(varchar(5),@cnt)+')
then CAST(c.APS_Dev as decimal(10,2)) end) as ''APS Dev'' '
```

2) to use `CONCAT` function for strings concatenation

```
SET @sqlQuery += CONCAT('max(CASE WHEN Cluster_ID = (Select STORE_ID from Table_Name where id= ',@cnt,')
then CAST(c.APS_Dev as decimal(10,2)) end) as ''APS Dev'' ')
```